# Plugin was not found with building gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

Having a gradle project.
When i'm trying to build project.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.hidetake:gradle-swagger-generator-plugin:2.9.0"
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.21"
    }
}
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.15"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.15"
}
```

I have error which is connected with plugins
`Plugin [id: 'net.ltgt.apt-eclipse', version: '0.15'] was not found in any of the following sources:`

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to find the solution to this issue?
I faced a similar issue, I have this error in the subproject with the same plugin and `org.springframework.boot` plugin as well.

Comment: try to change version in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper,properties and gradle:clean

Comment: Well, Recently i just saw README of this plugin on github. It says don't use this plugin. It's totally deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: If you are using a current gradle version, it's fine to just drop all of the net.ltgt.apt dependencies. You will not need it anymore because, it's features are now available natively in Gradle.

More details:
From the plugin README.md (https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin#readme)

> The goal of this plugin was to eventually no longer be needed, being superseded by built-in features. This has become a reality with Gradle 5.2 and IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1. tl;dr: this plugin is obsolete, don't use it. If you're using Eclipse though, continue reading.
>
> It originally did a few things to make it easier/safer to use Java annotation processors in a Gradle build. Those things are now available natively in Gradle, so what's this plugin about?
>
> If you use older versions of Gradle (pre-4.6), you can still benefit from those features:
>
> it ensures the presence of configurations for your compile-time only dependencies (annotations, generally) and annotation processors, consistently across all supported Gradle versions;
>
> automatically configures the corresponding JavaCompile and GroovyCompile tasks to make use of these configurations, when the java or groovy plugin is applied.
>
> With recent versions of Gradle (between 4.6 and 5.1), this plugin will actually only:
>
> add some DSL to configure annotation processors; it is however recommended to directly configure the tasks' options.compilerArgs;
> backport the sourceSet.output.generatedSourcesDirs Gradle 5.2 API;
> configure JavaCompile and GroovyCompile tasks' options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory with a sane default value so you can see the generated sources in your IDE and for debugging, and avoid shipping them in your JARs.

Comment: Gradle newbie... how do I "drop all of the net.ltgt.apt dependencies"

Comment: Got it.. just removed it from plugins list in build.gradle file of that project

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In `build.gradle`, the paths provided for the dependencies weren't matching the folders specified. Placing the folders in the mentioned path shown in the `build.gradle` solved it. After that I was able to build the project without errors.